# Get stored procedures parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I try to write code to get the parameters from a stored procedure

```
procedure get_proc_parameters(
      in_package_name     in user_arguments.PACKAGE_NAME%type,
      in_procedure_name   in user_arguments.OBJECT_NAME%type,
      io_cursor           in out t_ref_cursor
      )
is

begin

  open io_cursor for
   select ua.ARGUMENT_NAME PARAM_NAME,ua.SEQUENCE PARAM_ORDER
   from user_arguments ua
   where ua.PACKAGE_NAME=in_package_name
     and ua.OBJECT_NAME=in_procedure_name
     and ua.in_out='IN'
order by ua.SEQUENCE;
exception

end get_proc_parameters;
```

The code works fine when i have a package name, but no when is null.
I have some procedures out of packages.
The code is running if I have:

```
  where ua.PACKAGE_NAME is null
```

and not when:

```
where ua.PACKAGE_NAME = null.
```

How can I make my code work for both situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play around it

```
  SELECT UA.ARGUMENT_NAME PARAM_NAME, UA.SEQUENCE PARAM_ORDER
    FROM USER_ARGUMENTS UA
   WHERE     NVL (UA.PACKAGE_NAME, '1') = NVL (IN_PACKAGE_NAME, '1')
         AND UA.OBJECT_NAME = IN_PROCEDURE_NAME
         AND UA.IN_OUT = 'IN'
ORDER BY UA.SEQUENCE;
```

Answer (score 0):

please, try to use `nvl`

```
 open io_cursor for
   select ua.ARGUMENT_NAME PARAM_NAME,ua.SEQUENCE PARAM_ORDER
   from user_arguments ua
   where ua.PACKAGE_NAME=nvl(in_package_name, ua.PACKAGE_NAME)
   and ua.OBJECT_NAME=nvl(in_procedure_name, ua.OBJECT_NAME)
   and ua.in_out='IN'
```

UPD. You have comma after 'PARAM_ORDER' which is not needed